# Can there be a continuous probability distribution with a finite support that has an infinite second moment? Why?

Tags: probability

Could we define a continuous probability distribution with a finite support and infinite second momentum? Is there a mathematical language proof to that?

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ has distribution with finite (or compact) support then all moments are finite because $X$ is a bounded random variable.